# Anyone try playing animated gifs manually?

Tags: android

I need to display a simple animation (about 20 frames, each frame being about 40 x 40 pixels in size).

Ideally I would use an animated gif for this, but android < 2.2 does not support it, amazingly.

I'm wondering if anyone has experience composing the individual frames into a manual animation. This is what I believe we have to do. Any experience with the playback being choppy? Kind of don't want to start if the results are going to be poor.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a facility in Android for doing this. See the graphics documentation on Frame animation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

It includes a sample project that you can run so that you can determine if the performance will be sufficient for your needs.